# Interface implementation is not getting reference

Tags: java, interface, implementation

My implementation class of interface is not getting referenced at runtime.  Please let me know how to make it work at runtime.  There are no compilation errors

My App's interface is ::

```
public interface BiometricIntegrationAPI
{   
void captureBiometrics(CaptureHandler callback);
}
```

My App's interface implementation is `in.sampleapp.BiometricIntegrationImpl.Java`

```
public final class BiometricIntegrationImpl implements BiometricIntegrationAPI {

    @Override
    public void captureBiometrics(final CaptureHandler callback){
        // TODO...
    }
}
```

I tried to instantiate the object using:

```
biometricIntegrationAPI = (BiometricIntegrationAPI) Class.forName("in.sampleapp.BiometricIntegrationImpl").newInstance();
```

When I run my app, it is unable instantiate & unable to find reference to object  `BiometricIntegrationImpl` though there is BiometricIntegrationImpl.java file which has the class defined & methods related

Comment: What error do you get? It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, rather than just snippets.

Comment: Have you put the correct package statement at the top of your Java file?

Comment: Is this the "complete" full qualified name? : "in.sampleapp.BiometricIntegrationImpl"

Comment: Did you compile `BiometricIntegrationImpl.java` and made sure the class is available in the classpath when you run your program?

Comment: Did you try adding the `final` keyword to the parameter in the interface as well?

Comment: is your package name is correct?  can you share the error details?

Answer (score 0):

Without the compiler/runtime output we're guessing here, but you posted

```
biometricIntegrationAPI = (BiometricIntegrationAPI) Class.forName("in.sampleapp.BiometricIntegrationImpl").newInstance();
```

Hopefully, there is

```
BiometricIntegrationAPI biometricIntegrationAPI = null;
```

somewhere above the Class.forName() call.   But very likely your runtime CLASSPATH cannot find the class, or cannot find the jar with `in.sampleapp.BiometricIntegrationImpl`